# Navigating to other page but page is blank in Ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

In this bunch of code app navigate to `MapPage` but blank page appears not only `mappage` in to any pages.

```
   this.navCtrl.push(MapPage, { UDI: this.UID, Token: Token });
   this.navCtrl.setRoot(MapPage ,{ UDI: this.UID, Token: Token });
   this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
```

complete code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, AlertController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginService } from '../../providers/login-service';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
//import { NativeStorage } from 'ionic-native';9903601
import { DashboardPage } from '../dashboard/dashboard';
import { MapPage} from '../map/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    providers: [LoginService]
})
export class LoginPage {
    public UID: any;
    masks: any;
    public phoneNumber: any = "";
    public Token;
    public data;

    constructor(public platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController, public loginservice: LoginService, public http: Http, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
        this.masks = {
            phoneNumber: ['+', '9', '1', '-', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
        };
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.GetUID();
    }

    GetUID() {
        this.loginservice.UIDload()
            .then(data => {
                this.UID = data;
            });
    }

    GetActivation() {
        this.http.get('http://mydomain/sendverification/' + this.UID + '/' + this.phoneNumber + '/' + 'android1')
            .map(res => res.text())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.data = data;
                this.data = this.data.replace(/\n/g, "");
                this.data = this.data.replace(/\t/g, "");
                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: "4 digit activation code sent to you",
                    inputs: [{
                        name: 'activationcode',
                        placeholder: 'activation code'
                    }],
                    buttons: [{
                        text: 'next',
                        role: 'next',
                        handler: data => {
                            this.http.get('http://mydomain/chekverification/' + this.UID + '/' + data.activationcode)
                                .map(res => res.text())
                                .subscribe(Token => {
                                    console.log(Token);
                                    this.navCtrl.push(MapPage, { UDI: this.UID, Token: Token });
                                    this.navCtrl.setRoot(MapPage ,{ UDI: this.UID, Token: Token });
                                    this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
                                });
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'retry',
                        role: 'retry',
                        handler: data => {
                            this.GetActivation();
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                });
                alert.present();
            });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *only one* of the three functions:

```
this.navCtrl.push(MapPage, { UDI: this.UID, Token: Token });
```

This will push MapPage on to the navigation stack.

```
 this.navCtrl.setRoot(MapPage ,{ UDI: this.UID, Token: Token });
```

This will set MapPage as root of the stack *and load the page*.

```
 this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
```

This will pop all the pages in the stack till the current root of the stack.

In your case only do:

```
 this.navCtrl.setRoot(MapPage ,{ UDI: this.UID, Token: Token });
```

Comment: Hi @suraj thanKs for your help those 3 lines was working till last days.

Comment: not sure why it would work.. they all return promises. it is possible that they return at different times..http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/